# Converting a list of datetime objects to a list of number of days since a certain date

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I have a large list of dates that are datetime objects like for example

```
[datetime.datetime(2016,8,14),datetime.datetime(2016,8,13),datetime.datetime(2016,8,12),....etc.]
```

Instead of datetime objects of the date what I want instead is a list of numerical integer values since the date **1/1/1900**. I have defined 1/1/1900 as the base date and in the *for* loop below, I have calculated the days between the date in the list since that base date:

```
baseDate = datetime(1900,1,1)
numericalDates = []
for i in enumerate(dates):
    a=i[1]-baseDate
    numericalDates.append(a)

print(numericalDates)
```

However when I print this out, I get *datetime.timedelta* objects instead

```
[datetime.timedelta(42592), datetime.timedelta(42591), datetime.timedelta(42590),...etc.]
```

Any ideas on how I can convert it the proper way?

Comment: You need to use 30/12/1989 for the exact equivalent of Excel's by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9574793/2285236 (see the comments in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timedelta` objects have `days` attribute, so you can simply append that as an `int`:

```
numericalDates.append(a.days)
```

will result with `numericalDates` being `[42594, 42593, 42592]`.

Note that you can also simplify your code a bit by using list comprehension:

```
numericalDates = [(d - baseDate).days for d in dates]
```