# xlwings - early dates (<=1900's)

Tags: pandas, xlwings

Note:

```
xw.__version__
Out[84]: '0.10.2'
pd.__version__
Out[85]: '0.16.2'
```

I have the following df:

```
>>> df.head()
    data
1900-01-31  0.0315
1900-02-28  0.0314583333333
1900-03-31  0.0314166666667
1900-04-30  0.031375
1900-05-31  0.0313333333333
```

and when I run:

```
xw.sheets(str(sht)).range(k).value = d_of_dfs[k]
```

I see the following in excel:

```
            data
1900-02-01  0.0315
1900-02-29  0.031458333
1900-03-31  0.031416667
1900-04-30  0.031375
1900-05-31  0.031333333
1900-06-30  0.031291667
1900-07-31  0.03125
1900-08-31  0.031208333
1900-09-30  0.031166667
1900-10-31  0.031125
```

is xlwings hijacking the early date and messing it up?

Also - xlwings cannot handle dates prior to 1900 at all.

Answer (score 3):

This issue stems from the way excel stores dates and a bug that harkens back to Lotus 123.

From http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm

> Dates
>
> The integer portion of the number, ddddd, represents the number of
>   days since 1900-Jan-0.  For example, the date 19-Jan-2000 is stored as
>   36,544, since 36,544 days have passed since 1900-Jan-0.  The number 1
>   represents 1900-Jan-1.  It should be noted that the number 0 does not
>   represent 1899-Dec-31.  It does not. If you use the MONTH function
>   with the date 0, it will return January, not December.  Moreover, the
>   YEAR function will return 1900, not 1899.
>
> Actually, this number is one greater than the actual number of days. 
>   This is because Excel behaves as if the date 1900-Feb-29 existed.  It
>   did not.  The year 1900 was not a leap year (the year 2000 is a leap
>   year).  In Excel, the day after 1900-Feb-28 is 1900-Feb-29.  In
>   reality, the day after 1900-Feb-28  was 1900-Mar-1 .  This is not a
>   "bug".  Indeed, it is by design.  Excel works this way because it was
>   truly a bug in Lotus 123.  When Excel was introduced, 123 has nearly
>   the entire market for spreadsheet software.  Microsoft decided to
>   continue Lotus' bug, in order to fully compatible.  Users who switched
>   from 123 to Excel would not have to make any changes to their data.
>   As long as all your dates later than 1900-Mar-1, this should be of no
>   concern.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574793/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-datetime-to-excel-serial-date-number) has more detail though I've just been converting the date to string which excel seems to parse correctly.

```
converted = str(datetime.date(1900, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Given the integration of xlwings w pandas I would assume this would be handled.