# python xlsxwriter won't align dates

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Dates wind up in the bottom right corner of a cell, apparently ignoring alignment settings from xlsxwriter. A MWE:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        "ints": [1, 2, 3]
        , 'primes': [2, 3, 5]
        , 'odds': [1, 3, 5]
        , 'fechas': ['2017-04-07', '2017-05-09', '2017-11-30'] 
    }
)

df['fechas'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['fechas']).dt.date

print(df)

xlsx_writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(
    'test.xlsx'
    , engine='xlsxwriter'
    , date_format='mm/dd/yyyy'
)

df.to_excel(xlsx_writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
wb = xlsx_writer.book
ws = xlsx_writer.sheets['Sheet1']


dollar_format = '_($* #,##0.00" "_);_($* (#,##0.0);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)'
dollar_format_wb = wb.add_format({'num_format': dollar_format, 'valign': 'vcenter'})
centre_format_wb = wb.add_format({'align': 'center', 'valign': 'vcenter'})

ws.set_column('A:A', 25, centre_format_wb)
ws.set_column('B:B', 20, centre_format_wb)
ws.set_column('C:C', 15, centre_format_wb)
ws.set_column('D:D', 10, dollar_format_wb)

# The code below was included to generate the screenshot, but isn't
# strictly necessary for the MWE
shadedrow_format_wb = wb.add_format(
    {
        'bg_color': '#EEEEEE'
        , 'left': 1
        , 'left_color': '#FFFFFF'
    }
)

for r in range(0, 2 + df.shape[0]):
    ws.set_row(r + 1, 45)
    print(r)
    if r % 2 == 0:
        # a kludge as we can't change cell range formats after the fact without re-entering cell contents
        ws.conditional_format('A{:}:D{:}'.format(r, r), {'type': 'no_errors', 'format': shadedrow_format_wb})
        print("\t", r)

xlsx_writer.save()
```

Columns A, B, and C should be centered horizontally, and all rows except the header should be height 45, with all cell contents centered vertically.

[image: excel screen shot]

Everything works like it should, **except for the date column**. Is there a good reason that this shouldn't work? Is there a correct way of getting the date centred? Is it a bug? Is there a work-around?

I have also tried formatting the sheet first, and performing the `df.to_excel()` last, with no effect.

Many thanks!

Comment: apologies -- I neglected to state that edits were minor for better comprehension (and made title more exact)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've provided an example of how you can achieve your desired date formatting in a .xlsx output using pandas.  It would also require adding the datetime module.

As @jmcnamara mentioned, I think the best and most flexible solution would be to use xlsxwriter directly.

Here's a [link to another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574793/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-datetime-to-excel-serial-date-number) that provides further background on the excel "serial date" format and getting it from a datetime object in python.  This is essentially the same as what I did to convert the column to an excel date.  I've also added an additional format (called "centre_date_format_wb").

Here's the full code with my additions/changes:

```
import pandas
import datetime

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        "ints": [1, 2, 3]
        , 'primes': [2, 3, 5]
        , 'odds': [1, 3, 5]
        , 'fechas': ['2017-04-07', '2017-05-09', '2017-11-30'] 
    }
)

df['fechas'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['fechas']).dt.date


excel_start_date = datetime.date(1899, 12, 30)
df['fechas'] = df['fechas'] - excel_start_date
df.fechas = df.fechas.dt.days

print(df)

xlsx_writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(
    'test.xlsx'
    , engine='xlsxwriter'
)

df.to_excel(xlsx_writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
wb = xlsx_writer.book
ws = xlsx_writer.sheets['Sheet1']


dollar_format = '_($* #,##0.00" "_);_($* (#,##0.0);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)'
dollar_format_wb = wb.add_format({'num_format': dollar_format, 'valign': 'vcenter'})
centre_format_wb = wb.add_format({'align': 'center', 'valign': 'vcenter'})
#additional format added below
centre_date_format_wb = wb.add_format({'align': 'center', 'valign': 'vcenter', 'num_format' : 'mm/dd/yyyy' })

ws.set_column('A:A', 25, centre_date_format_wb)
ws.set_column('B:B', 20, centre_format_wb)
ws.set_column('C:C', 15, centre_format_wb)
ws.set_column('D:D', 10, dollar_format_wb)

# The code below was included to generate the screenshot, but isn't
# strictly necessary for the MWE
shadedrow_format_wb = wb.add_format(
    {
        'bg_color': '#EEEEEE'
        , 'left': 1
        , 'left_color': '#FFFFFF'
    }
)

for r in range(0, 2 + df.shape[0]):
    ws.set_row(r + 1, 45)
    print(r)
    if r % 2 == 0:
        # a kludge as we can't change cell range formats after the fact without re-entering cell contents
        ws.conditional_format('A{:}:D{:}'.format(r, r), {'type': 'no_errors', 'format': shadedrow_format_wb})
        print("\t", r)

xlsx_writer.save()
```

And an image of the resulting worksheet:

[image: Solution image]

Comment: Beautiful @patrickjlong1 ! Thank you! Excel base dates do my head in -- do you know whether this will work cross-platform?

Comment: @GoneSync, I think the the example should have no cross-platform issues.  It stays away directory/folder paths so I think it should be safe for Linux or windows.

Comment: Excel base dates do my head in -- I was more worried about the differences between versions and platforms in the base dates -- I *think* older versions of excel were off by a day owing to purposely replicating a bug in Lotus 1-2-3, and Mac used 1904 instead ... I possibly have that wrong, but the chaos was something I always tried to avoid by relying on developers who spend more time thinking about it than me. I've accepted this as the answer, although as you say @jmcnamara's suggestion will be a possibly more robust fallback if I run into trouble down the track. Thanks to both of you!!

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that Pandas is applying a cell format for the date and this overrides the column format.

The only way to workaround it would be iterate over the dataframe and write to XlsxWriter directly, applying all the formats that you want.

Comment: Thank you @jmcnamara -- I'll take it up with pandas, and use your suggestion in the meantime.

Comment: I've had success by converting my date column to astype(str) just before writing to Excel. Then the XlsxWriter formatting on my date works.