# python datetime to excel serial number

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, datetime

How to convert (YY,MM,DD,HH,MM,SS) to the Excel "serial" datetime number.

Example: 12/23/2017  10:00:00 PM to 43092.91667

Below converts the date only, but I need to add the timestamp as well:

```
def convertDateToExcel(day, month, year) :
    offset = 693594
    itime = date(year,month,day)
    n = itime.toordinal()
    return (n - offset)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a python datetime.datetime to excel serial date number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574793/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-datetime-to-excel-serial-date-number)

Answer (score 1):

A prime example of me overthinking the problem :-)

The obvious answer:

```
   def convertDateToExcel(year, month, day, hour, minute, second) :
          offset = 693594
          itime = date(year,month,day)
          n = itime.toordinal()
          return (n - offset + (60*60*hour + 60*minute + second)/(24*60*60))
```