# How to get the excel datetime as a FLOAT number rather than a 'datetime.datetime' in xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, datetime, xlwings

My code is as below, and the text.xlsx file looks like:
[image: text.xlsx file screenshot].

```py
import xlwings as xw
import datetime

app = xw.App(visible=False,add_book=False)
file_path = r'D:\test.xlsx'
wb = app.books.open(file_path)
sht = wb.sheets[0]
cell = sht.range((1, 1)).value
print(cell)

wb.close()
app.quit()
```

In the test file, the datetime in 'A1' is **(1895, 10, 24, 23, 2, 24)**, which stores in excel as **-1528.96**, but I don't care about this datetime right now, I just want to get the **excel number -1528.96** in my code, but it failed.

The print message is:

```
1895-10-24 23:02:24
```

Expected meassage is:

```
-1528.96
```

Also tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9574948/12525445, but the result is **-1527.04**

Many thanks for any clue!

Comment: Did you see the answer in the linked question?  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24410858/198536)

Comment: @wallyk Thank you, but I want to get the excel datetime number as a float type not the formatted datetime string.

Comment: In theory, we should add the `value2` property. For now just do: `sht.range((1, 1)).api.Value2`

Comment: @FelixZumstein Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I am looking for. BTW, where can I learn this `api` API, the xlwings documentation seems to be no such part.

Comment: On Windows, it's pretty much standard VBA object model, so usually you start at the official microsoft docs: In your case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2

Comment: @FelixZumstein - If you get a chance, I think you should gather the knowledge from these comments and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way of getting the underlying float from an Excel date would be to call the `value2` property. Unfortunately, we haven't implemented this just yet in xlwings, so you'll need to drop down to pywin32, if you are on Windows:

```
sht.range((1, 1)).api.Value2
```

Learn more about how to handle missing features here: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html

The syntax on Windows for `.api` is really pywin32 syntax which again is almost the same as the official VBA way of doing it. In your specific case, you can refer to the official Microsoft docs for Value2: 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2