# python: pasting a date in 'dd/mm/yyyy' to excel converts it to 'mm/dd/yyyy'

Tags: python, excel, date

I am trying to paste a date using python code onto an excel cell

`ws.Range('A1').Value = '11/06/2020'` i.e. 11 June 2020

and what I see in that excel cell is `06/11/2020` i.e. 6th of November 2020.

Any clues what is going on?

Running this on my windows, same code on my Mac runs fine!

codes, if anyone interested

```
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
xlapp.Workbooks.Open('C:\\blp\\API\\Office Tools\\BloombergUI.xla')
xlapp.RegisterXLL('C:/blp/API/Office Tools/bofaddin.dll')
filepath = give the path here
wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(filepath,None,False)
xlapp.Visible = True
wb_addin = ('C:/blp/API/Office Tools/bofaddin.dll')
ws = wb.Worksheets[‘AB’]
ws.Range('A18').Value = '11/06/2020'
```

additional comments:
btw feels like its an issue when you use win32com. I just tried using openpyxl and it worked fine. unfortunately I have to use BBG addins in my excel and that works the best with win32com it seems

Comment: Excel will parse the string according to `short date` **Windows Regional Settings** of the computer on which it is running. So your windows computer likely has `MDY` for its short date setting.  I'm not into Python, but [this to convert to an Excel serial number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574793/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-datetime-to-excel-serial-date-number) might be helpful.

Comment: no I just checked and it shows Short date : dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Maybe just the formatting on the excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Do format the DateTime or apply the format to your worksheet because based on the regional DateTime settings it will differ like `MDY` or `DMY`

If you're using `xlsxwriter` writer engine use below code:

```
formatdict = {'num_format':'mm/dd/yyyy'}
fmt = workbook.add_format(formatdict)
```

Please add your sample code or post some more information about your libraries.

Comment: I check its DMY (my comment above) , I am using win32com. will your code work on that as well?

Comment: what package you're using to write excel?

Comment: btw feels like its an issue when you use win32com. I just tried using openpyxl and it worked fine. unfortunately I have to use BBG addins in my excel and that works the best with win32com it seems

Answer (score 0):

There is differents date format e.g `dd/mm/yy`, `mm/dd/yy`, etc... your version of excel probably uses this format `mm/dd/yy`, to convert `dd/mm/yy` format in `mm/dd/yy` you can try this:

```
date1 = '22/7/1'
d_excel = date1.split('/')
d_excel[0], d_excel[1] = d_excel[1],d_excel[0]
print('/'.join(d_excel))
```