# Changing Excel Dates (As integers) mixed with timestamps in single column - Have tried str.extract

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column of dates, unfortunately my import (using read_excel) brought in format of dates as datetime and also excel dates as integers.

What I am seeking is a column with dates only in format %Y-%m-%d

From research, excel starts at 1900-01-00, so I could add these integers. I have tried to use str.extract and a regex in order to separate the columns into two, one of datetimes, the other as integers. However the result is NaN.

Here is an input code example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_from': [pd.Timestamp('2022-09-10 00:00:00'),44476, pd.Timestamp('2021-02-16 00:00:00')], 'date_to': [pd.Timestamp('2022-12-11 00:00:00'),44455, pd.Timestamp('2021-12-16 00:00:00')]})
```

[image: Output looks like below]

Attempt to first separate the columns by extracting the integers( dates imported from MS excel)

```
df.date_from.str.extract(r'(\d\d\d\d\d)')
```

however this gives NaN.

The reason I have tried to separate integers out of the column, is that I get an error when trying to act on the excel dates within the mixed column (in other words and error using the following code:)

```
def convert_excel_time(excel_time):

    return pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(excel_time,'D')
```

Any guidance on how I might get a column of dates only? I find the datetime modules and aspects of pandas and python the most frustrating of all to get to grips with!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with `errors='coerce'` for `NaT` if not integers add `Timestamp` called `d`, then convert datetimes with `errors='coerce'` and last pass to [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) in custom function:

```
def f(x):
    #https://stackoverflow.com/a/9574948/2901002
    d = pd.Timestamp(1899, 12, 30)
    timedeltas = pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='d', errors='coerce')
    dates = pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')
    return (timedeltas + d).fillna(dates)

cols = ['date_from','date_to']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(f)
print (df)
   date_from    date_to
0 2022-09-10 2022-12-11
1 2021-10-07 2021-09-16
2 2021-02-16 2021-12-16
```

Comment: thanks jezrael, however I get TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]. apologies I see your edit, let me try that now!!

Comment: Still gettingTypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]

Comment: @Prolle - what is your pandas version? Tested in `pandas 1.1.1`

Comment: My version is 1.0.5

Comment: all sorted now. Upgrade did the trick. thanks for your help