# pandas datetime convertion from excel integer

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a xlsb file with pandas read_excel.

```
df = pd.read_excel("..\df.xlsb",
                   sheet_name="Data",
                   engine='pyxlsb'
                   )
```

When I check the file, 'Date' column type is changing to excel integer format. I' m giving an example df below.

```
df = {'Date': [44409, 44409, 44410, 44410, 44411]
     }
```

I tried to_datetime function of pandas. But it gives 1970-01-01 result. I also tried several methods but nothing is changed.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit = 's') #trial1
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit = 'ns') #trial2
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = "%Y%m%d") #trial3
```

I want to see this time format. But I don't want use "for loop", because I have 19000 rows in original data.

```
    Date
0   2021-08-01
1   2021-08-01
2   2021-08-02
3   2021-08-02
4   2021-08-03
```

I also tried these solutions;

[Convert Excel style date with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454403/convert-excel-style-date-with-pandas)

[How to convert a python datetime.datetime to excel serial date number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574793/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-datetime-to-excel-serial-date-number#comment49502311_9574948)

Comment: For me it working perfecly `df['real_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='D', origin='1899-12-30')`

Comment: It gives that error "Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]' is not compatible with origin='1899-12-30'; it must be numeric with a unit specified"

Comment: also another solutions failed? with  `df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [44409, 44409, 44410, 44410, 44411]
     })` ?

Comment: When I try this: """df['real_date'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['Date'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)"""  it gives that error --> TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]

Comment: I think need only `df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [44409, 44409, 44410, 44410, 44411]      })` and then `df['real_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='D', origin='1899-12-30')`

Comment: btw, your error means `Date` is already datetime, not integers

Comment: 'Date' is a dataframe column not a dictionary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236675/discussion-between-piseynir-and-jezrael).