# Get exact date format in Excel from Python Datetime field

Tags: python, django, excel

How can I get the exact format date in Excel?

I need to create an Excel sheet from some data (in my "models.py"  `date_result_stamp` it's `DateTime` field) in Django project and I don't know how I can pass the exact date (not `str` or another type of data) into Excel.

`result["date_result_stamp"] = datetime.strftime(result["date_result_stamp"], "%Y-%m-%d")`

It's `str` format and I need to get the `date` format.

Can you help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574793/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-datetime-to-excel-serial-date-number/24410858 Does this work for you?

Comment: If your using xlrd you could use their xldate_from_datetime_tuple function https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.xldate.xldate_from_datetime_tuple

Comment: Jimmy Pells, I use xlsxwriter

Comment: Maybe https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html will help looks like `worksheet.write_datetime(row, col, datetime.strftime(result["date_result_stamp"], "%Y-%m-%d"))`